# Happens-Before Relationship - What is an atomic object talking about concurrency in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, happens-before

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.races#8

> An evaluation A is dependency-ordered before an evaluation B if (8.1)
> A performs a release operation on an **atomic object M**, and, in another
> thread, B performs a consume operation on M and reads the value
> written by A, or (8.2) for some evaluation X, A is dependency-ordered
> before X and X carries a dependency to B. [ Note: The relation “is
> dependency-ordered before” is analogous to “synchronizes with”, but
> uses release/consume in place of release/acquire. — end note ]

¿"Atomic object" is **"something special"** in C++ or is it just a name given to any variable in the **context (when we talk about concurrency in c++)** of concurrency in C++?

*If it is something special*, **can you tell me what it is**?

Comment: Its something special.

Comment: and, what's? @tkausl +1

Comment: Please don't make your question rely on screen shots (or external links).  Include a transcription of the text.  Screen shots block searching, accessibility, and achiving.  Include them for extra details, and external links die.

Comment: See for instance [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: ready @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont, could you please help me now? :)

Comment: An atomic object is an object the respects the conditions that the standard imposes for atomic objects.  `std::atomic` for instance is one example of an atomic object, but there are in theory an infinite number of different atomic types.

Comment: hi @NathanOliver, so the concept of atomic object is a **concept of programming** and not so much of a specific programming language? +1

Comment: There's not even a single concept of atomic objects. There are atomically-updatable memory regions, depending on hardware platform details, plus more platform specific details around ordering and synchronization of updates to those regions, and these are finally expressed in C++ via `std::atomic` or `std::atomic_ref`, along with the compiler constraints needed to use them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to a relatively recent version of C++, atomic objects are just `std::atomic` stuff.  It was simple.  Now, it is more complex.

The introduction of `atomic_ref` changed this:

[atomics.ref.generic] 31.7/1 reads:

> An atomic_­ref object applies atomic operations ([atomics.general]) to the object referenced by *ptr such that, for the lifetime ([basic.life]) of the atomic_­ref object, the object referenced by *ptr is an atomic object ([intro.races]).

So atomic objects are `std::atomic<T>` and family (`std::atomic_bool` etc), *plus* anything wrapped by a `std::atomic_ref<T>`.  The `std::atomic_ref<T>` is not atomic, but the wrapped thing becomes so.

The idea is that these atomic objects are the objects for which atomic operations (which are a special kind of thread-safe operations in the C++ standard) can apply to.

The fact that "normal" objects that are no longer wrapped in `atomic_ref` are no longer atomic is important and tricky to think about.  I suspect this rule exists because some platforms implement atomics using lock-based operations.  On others, atomic operations can occur on most well-aligned memory.

```
std::atomic<int> a;
int b;
```

`a` is atomic, `b` is not.

```
{
   std::atomic_ref<int> x(b);
```

now `b` is an atomic object.

```
}
```

and now `b` is not an atomic object.

Comment: hi @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont +1 "The idea is that these atomic objects are the objects for which atomic operations (which are a special kind of thread-safe operations in the C++ standard) can apply to." - means that if an atomic object gives us an method for example to update itself, we don't have to worry about the synchronization since they do it for us, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer No, atomic objects have complex rules about how interact with the C++ memory model.  Threading is fundamentally hard, and "don't have to worry" is not something you can ever say regarding it.

Atomics are a way of interacting with the multithreaded model in a way that doesn't require locks.  But it isn't a "don't have to worry", it is just a different set of rules that (admittedly) can compose better than lock based.

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer C++'s memory model (which mainly deals with multi threading) is tricky to understand, but unlike most languages it is actually close to mathematically correct/reasonable.  Most languages punt and "you get what the implementation does", as they have one implementation and its behavior is the de facto standard.  C++ actually specifies how it works and when you can actually get guaranteed correct results.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest possible terms, an atomic object is an object of type `std::atomic<T>` or `std::atomic_ref<T>`.

These objects provide special operations for fine-grained atomic access to data that are subject to special guarantees from the language with regards to inter-thread synchronization, which form the basis of the C++ memory model.

See [intro.multithread] and [atomics.general] as the relevant sections in [the latest draft standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/n4892.pdf).

Comment: The problem with is is that `std::atomic_ref<T>` wraps a `T` -- is the `T` an atomic object?  If you have two different `std::atomic_ref<T>` to a single underlying object, are the changes made to the `T` or the refs?  I think it is the `T`!  Prior to `atomic_ref` this was easy; I wonder if we are looking at awkwardness due to its existence.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont See [atomics.ref.generic.general]: An atomic_ref object applies atomic operations to the object referenced by *ptr such that, for the
lifetime of the atomic_ref object, the object referenced by *ptr is an atomic object

Comment: More pertinently, [para 4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/atomics#ref.generic-4) reads _"Atomic operations applied to an object through a referencing atomic_­ref are atomic with respect to atomic operations applied through any other atomic_­ref referencing the same object."_

Comment: hi @ComicSansMS, then, by an "atomic object" we understand an object whose public interface exposes only atomic operations, i.e. all operations you can do with that object are atomic, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer No.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿"Atomic object" is "something special" in C++ or is it just a name given to any variable in the context (when we talk about concurrency in c++) of concurrency in C++?

Literally 5 paragraphs above the one you quoted is

> <sub>[3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.races#3)</sub>  The library defines a number of atomic operations ([atomics](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/atomics)) ...

> <sub>4</sub>  All modifications to a particular atomic object M ...

where the first mention of an *atomic object* comes immediately after the first reference to *atomic operations*, which links to the section describing only two new classes (well, class templates plus specializations): `std::atomic` and `std::atomic_ref`.

---

An atomic object is, in the broadest terms (**edit** for the avoidance of doubt, this means *with more generality than C++ or any individual language*), an object to which we can make *atomic* (meaning "indivisible") updates. So, another thread could read the old value, or the new value, but never a mixture of both.

That's not sufficient to actually *do* very much without:

1. either knowing something about a specific platform's memory subsystem (which would be non-portable) or *also* providing a way to specify the ordering constraints needed on a particular load or store
2. providing some way to prevent the compiler reordering (or eliding) loads or stores inappropriately

All three of those things (indivisibility, explicit ordering and compiler control) are bundled together into the `std::atomic` and `std::atomic_ref` wrappers, with the necessary support from the C++ memory model.

Before this language support (the memory model plus the atomics library), the best we could do was write platform-specific code using intrinsics or assembler, or platform-specific libraries like pthreads.

Comment: Hi @Useless *An atomic object is, in the broadest terms, an object to which we can make atomic (meaning "indivisible") updates. So, another thread could read the old value, or the new value, but never a mixture of both* - that's what is known as **happens-before relation**, right?

Comment: No, that sentence is talking about word tearing, not ordering. You're trying to relate _everything_ everyone says about this field to a technical-but-abstract standards document, without understanding either the technical background being abstracted or how hard it is to read standards. They're not educational texts and need some experience to interpret.